# IPP CustomerAgg 401 on getAccountTransactions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

The user flow I'm building for my application is that users can click on myAccounts and I'll display the getCustomerAccounts Results. That works perfectly. Then for each account I have a hyperlink called get transactions. That takes the user to a new page that should list out the transactions for that account. For some reason I'm always getting a 401 Code:ApplicationAuthenticationFailed when I call getAccountTransactions even though the previous call of getCustomerAccounts worked fine.

I'm confused as I imagine the authentication that is failing for the 401 is the exact same that works for the earlier call. Here is my code:

function get_transactions($accountID)

```
{

    IntuitAggCatHelpers::GetOAuthTokens( $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

    $signatures = array( 'consumer_key'     => OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,

        'shared_secret'    => OAUTH_SHARED_SECRET,

        'oauth_token'      => $oauth_token,

        'oauth_secret'     => $oauth_token_secret);





    $txnStartDate = '2014-06-01';  // YYYY-MM-DD

    $url = FINANCIAL_FEED_URL ."v1/accounts/$accountID/transactions?txnStartDate=$txnStartDate";

    $action = 'GET';



    $oauthObject = new OAuthSimple();

    $oauthObject->setAction( $action );

    $oauthObject->reset();



    $result = $oauthObject->sign(

        array

        (

            'path'      => $url,

            'parameters'=>

                array

                (

                    'oauth_signature_method'    => 'HMAC-SHA1',

                    'Host'  => FINANCIAL_FEED_HOST

                ),

            'signatures'=> $signatures

        )

    );



    $options = array();

    $curlError = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');

    $options[CURLOPT_STDERR] = $curlError;

    $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = $action;

    $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $result['signed_url'];

    $options[CURLOPT_HEADER] = 1;

    $options[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = 1;

    $options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = 1;

    $options[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;

    $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array

    (

        'Accept:application/json',

        'Content-Type:application/json',

        //'Content-Length:' . strlen( $postData ),

        'Host:'. FINANCIAL_FEED_HOST,

        //'Authorization:' . $result['header']

    );



    $curlError = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');

    $options[CURLOPT_STDERR] = $curlError;



    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    $responseText = urldecode( curl_exec( $ch ) );

    echo $responseText;

    //display curl http conversation

    rewind( $curlError );

    stream_get_contents( $curlError );

    fclose( $curlError );

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

    curl_close( $ch );

    return $responseText;
```

}

Comment: What is type of account of account you are getting? Is it other? https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0030_getaccounttransactions  Please call updateAccountType to get the exact account type, then try your call.Also check if your tokens did not expire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The account is not other and my token is active as other calls work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Since your app is not in Prod, see if you have not reached the throttle limit for this customer 20 customer, 10 accounts per customer. Delete all accounts for your customer and then try you above code.

Answer (score 0):

Using same certificate(.p12) please try the above getAccountTransaction call from APIExplorer tool.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData

Usage Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

If that works well, then compare the request header and URL with the same from your above code. 401 suggests authentication error which comes when your OAuth header is not properly formed/incorrect. Above comparison should sort this out.

**PN** - While uploading .p12 file(SAML) in ApiExplorer, sometiems, I get the following error msg. 
"Your certificate is invalid. Please use base64 encoded CER format and make sure that the file is not empty". If you get the same then this can't be tested in ApiExplorer.

Thanks

Comment: According to what I've seen that last comment of yours - "your certificate is invalid..." happens when your browser session expires. Refreshing the browser won't show it(!). You need to explicitly log out -> then login again -> try the same API method again, in the API explorer (after loading the p12 file + matching password). It works (worked this way to me).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$result = $oauthObject->sign(array(
    'path'      => FINANCIAL_FEED_URL . 'v1/accounts/400037865348',
    'parameters'=> array('oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1', 
    'Host'=> FINANCIAL_FEED_HOST,
    'txnStartDate' => '2014-01-01',
    'txnEndDate' => '2014-08-29'),
    'signatures'=> $signatures));
```

Found at https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/797819-how-to-get-txnstartdate-into-my-url-without-breaking-oauth-authentication.